# What are the sizes of the hex nut drivers in the classic "nine piece" computer toolkit

Tags: case

Back in the 1990's many vendors sold those cheap nine piece kits that held, among other things, two Philips screwdrivers: #1 and #2, a couple of flat head screwdrivers, and a pair of hex nut drivers.  For me, the most common use of these last two was screwing the standoffs into the bottom of the case to mount the motherboard.

What sizes were these two, because among the entire collection of bits I have for my electric screwdriver, I have a complete lack of hex nut drivers.  I've started rebuilding systems out of parts I have, to be given away to charity, and it would be nice to have these two bits added to my collection.

Comment: This question looks off-topic: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JimNelson disagree. This is a question about tools for repairing and maintaining on-topic machines. It may be less than optimally worded but it's nowhere near off-topic.

Comment: On topic or not, this question could be resolved quite quickly if the person who started this thread took a calliper and measured those nuts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [one of these](https://amzn.to/3f6Ywim):

[image]

This one is actually an 11-piece. But same basic stuff.

I've used & lost quite a few of these over the years.

According to the specs:

> Includes Nut driver 1/4 inch / Nut driver 3/16 inch

Which sounds about right. I was sure one was 1/4". And I was sure they were US sizes rather than metric sizes. The only question in my mind was what the second size was. And the answer is apparently 3/16".

Comment: Interesting.  All of the three that I owned were nine-piece, the two items missing were the tweezers on the left side of that image and the reversible Torx driver.  Anyway, I've marked this as the answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: The 3/16" size  nutdriver mated to the jackscrew items in DA-9 (serial) and DA-15 (VGA video) and also DVI.